# Identify empty xml files?

Tags: find, xml

I have a requirement to identify and write all xml file names which are empty to a text file for reporting purpose. Empty , here means the xml file has the usual header tag `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` followed by an empty open and close tag.

Sample file:
1)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<STBTests>
</STBTests>
```

2)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<UMTTests>
</UMTTests>
```

There are no data in the xml files apart from this. Any suggestions on how to approach this would be great.

Comment: Can you be specific about how you define an "empty" file? Is it (at most) one tag on the first line, followed by pairs of open and close tags with nothing but whitespace between them?

Comment: How about file size, it could be a good tell if non-empty files are bigger, use `find /path -size -128c` to find files with less than 128 bytes

Comment: other option is to count the lines, `for F in *.xml; do if [ $(wc -l "$F") -lt 4 ]; then echo "$F"; fi; done`

Comment: @Dalvenjia: very bad idea. Think of an inline node like `<foo>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</foo>`

Comment: What about comments and processing instructions?

Comment: @Sparhawk that correct. The sample file given above is the actual file that i am dealing with.

Comment: @Dalvenjia well, majority of these empty files are 1kb but there are some cases where the file is 1 kb but has one records. In such cases this would fail .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using [xmllint](/questions/tagged/xmllint) with a [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) expression :

```
#!/bin/sh

for xml in *.xml; do
    bool=$(xmllint --xpath 'count(//*)=1 and string-length(//*[1])=1' "$xml")
    if [ $bool = true ]; then
        echo "$xml" >> xml_list_files
    fi
done

cat xml_list_files
```

The expression test that the file have only one node without any text content. In this case, the command return `true`

Comment: This is what exactly i was looking for, works like a charm! Thanks a lot bud! Really appreciate the quick response.

Comment: Thanks. Don't forget to accept/vote up if it fit your needs :)

Comment: I had fun finding the solution, not _that_ easy at a first glance

Comment: Awesome! I know !!! you are a genius sir! I have been braking my head around this with the very limited unix knowledge i got. Am glad i asked here. This the first time am on this website, and definitely not the last. Am gonna try and help others in need like this :) Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your clear question, well formatted. If it's your first question, it's quite good ;)

Answer (score 0):

> to identify and write all xml file names which are empty to a text
>   file for reporting purpose

**`find`** + **`xmlstarlet`** solution:

```
find . -type f -name "*.xml" -exec bash -c \
'v=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -i "count(//*)=1 and //*[1][not(normalize-space())]" -o 1 -b $1);
[[ -n "$v" ]] && echo "$1" >> "empty_xml.txt"' _ {} \;
```

---

`empty_xml.txt` file should contain a list of needed filenames/filepaths

Comment: Thanks a lot of the response bud. Unfortunately i was not able to use/test it as i don't have the xmlstartlet installed. Am gonna gonna try and get it installed and get back to you. Thanks again.